# Why is it true that $\text{sign}\left[\sum_{j=1}^m \operatorname{sign}(W_j \cdot x)\right]= \operatorname{sign}\left[\sum_{j=1}^m W_j \cdot x\right]$

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, proof-writing

$\newcommand{\sign}{\operatorname{sign}}$Why is it true that:
$$\sign\left[\sum_{j=1}^m \sign(W_j \cdot x)\right]= \sign\left[\sum_{j=1}^m W_j \cdot x\right]$$

when $m \rightarrow \infty $

[EDIT]
Variables Definition

$W_{j}, x \in \mathrm{R}^{m}$

All the entries of $x$ are +1 or -1

$W_{j}$ is such that it is in the version space. The version space is formed by all $W_{j}$ that make the training error equal zero. The training error is given by: $\mathbb{P}(\text{sign} (y.x)\, \text{sign}(W_{j}.x))$

$(x,y)$ are vectors of the training set, that is, for every entrie $x$ we know what is the response $y$

Comment: What is $ W_j $?

Comment: @FreeSalad it is a vector

Comment: Tried helping with typesetting, not sure I got it right though.

Comment: @FreeSalad I defined the variables in the EDIT

Comment: I made an important edit: The $W_{j}$ are suck that they make the trainning error.